# Any tools to do UI automation testing for android/hybrid application?

Tags: android, testing, ui-automation, android-testing

I want to test android app, by recording the steps of a test case and run it more than one time like monkey talk tool.
Please help me on this.

I tried to use monkey talk, the tool is not exists in the official site.
Tried Appium studio community edition, unable to run in my system due to some server license connectivity error.
Please sugget some other ways to test the app.

Thanks,
Tripaty

Comment: Do you really need the Recording functionality ?.

Comment: Yes, I need it to record the steps @DasunB